# wp_upload_bits() is not giving the file path right in localhost

Tags: uploads

I'm trying to upload files into a separate directory inside the `uploads/`, and I succeed using `wp_upload_bits()`. I's happy with everything and I thought thing was done.

But when I's trying to delete the files, as I **din't use** `wp_add_attachment()` etc. so I need to `unlink()` the file using its path. So I stored the file array. When I's trying to use the file path, I found it's broken.

```
X:xampphtdocswordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/filename.jpg
```

I was using WAMP in Windows. I tried using XAMPP. And then tried using Nginx 1.10.1 - the result is same. So I then checked the `wp_upload_dir()`:

```
var_dump(wp_upload_dir());
```

Problem is it's returning:

```
array(6) {
   ["path"]=> string(52) "X:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05"
   ["url"]=> string(53) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05"
   ["subdir"]=> string(8) "/2017/05"
   ["basedir"]=> string(44) "X:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads"
   ["baseurl"]=> string(45) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads"
   ["error"]=> bool(false)
}
```

You can see the problem is in slashes - a bad combination of forward (`/`) and back slashes (`\`) are there. And I guess that's what causing the issue.

I know I can make up the file path using `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and some hard coded strings, but I want to stick with the dynamic features as much as possible.

What can I do now?

## EDIT

I did quite a lot of works here. BTW I think only this part is the key:

```
$attachment_file = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['my_attachment']['name'][$key], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['my_attachment']['tmp_name'][$key]) );
```

The `$key` because there are multiple files and doing the same for each of 'em.

Comment: On Windows that's actually a perfectly valid file path, you can have a mix of forward and backward slashes. WordPress uses [`wp_normalize_path`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_normalize_path/) internally to fix this, but it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code that uses `wp_upload_bits` and does the other parts?

Comment: @TomJNowell added my code here.

Comment: @TomJNowell here is the code, it's a junk commit only to share things: https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/feature/ticket-attachment/includes/ns-metaboxes.php#L385-L442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same exact issue (getting paths like 'X:xampphtdocswordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/filename.jpg' on WAMP on Windows). The issue seems to be due to [update_post_meta() passing values through stripslashes()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta#Character_Escaping) when storing the data.

The workaround is to add wp_slash() around your value you pass to update_post_meta().

You're probably calling update_post_meta() something like this:

```
update_post_meta( $id, 'doesnt_work', $data );
```

You need to add wp_slash() to the data before or as you call update_post_meta()

```
update_post_meta( $id, 'does_work', wp_slash( $data ) );
```

The end result:

```
array ( 'file' => 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\wpdev\\wpdev_test/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/filename', ....
```